# Ways to get a pair in poker

Tags: combinations, poker

When drawing a pair the number of ways to get it is:

$${13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{12 \choose 3}(4)^3$$

But I don't understand why the following doesn't work:
$${13 \choose 1}{4 \choose 2}{12 \choose 1}{11 \choose 1}{10 \choose 1}(4)^3$$

Thanks a lot!

Btw This hand has 5 cards.

Comment: sorry I wrote the question wrong, I just changed it. My bad.

Comment: The second expression counts each one pair hand $6$ rimes, For example, the $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{1}$ counts 3 of clubs and Jack of hearts as different from Jack of hearts and three  of clubs.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. But why does it work to multiply the two parts of the equation. The first part of the equation accounts for pairs, and the second part accounts for other cards. Wouldn't multiplying these two give you double the answer because the order can be switched.

Comment: Multiplying only counts once, roughly speaking because the pair and the useless cards are different types of things. It is not that we choose the two Queens and then the thee useless cards. There is no temporal order implicit in the count. It is just that there are $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select the pair. An easier example, $10$ boys, $14$ girls, there are $(10)(14)$ ways to select a team consisting of a boy and a girl, no double-counting because we are selecting from different pools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the second way differs from the first by a factor of $3!$. This represents the fact that the other three cards can be drawn in any order. The second way is counting as two possibilities drawing the other three cards in two different orders, which is not what you want.

**Edit:** OP asked why we're not concerned with double counting when we simply multiply the "pair" part by the "other cards" part. Notice that in this case we're not double counting anything: it's not as if we've counted twice the possibility of JJ543 by multiplying. One might say that the pair is distinguishable from the other three cards, so there's no question of double counting them in different orders.

The trick with these things is to convince yourself in your mind that your formula has created a [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) between the possibilities and the things that you're counting. Instead of memorizing rules about order, etc., I would rather practice coming up with the bijection in your head, and checking that you haven't missed anything. Think "for each hand with a pair, there's a unique term in my counting, and for each term in my counting, there's a unique hand with a pair."

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense.So then why does it work to multiply the two parts of the equations together. The first part (which represents the pair) and the second part that represents the other 3 cards. Wouldn't that also be doubling the outcome?

Comment: Edited. :) ----

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your question here is what's the difference between $\binom{12}{3}$ and $\binom{12}{1} \binom{11}{1} \binom {10}{1}$. The difference is that the latter implicitly orders what you're picking. In this instance, you're picking the 3 cards in your hand that aren't part of the pair.

The former way of counting just picks three card values (e.g. 5, Q, A, not part of your pair, say K). The latter counts how many ways can I pick the first card, the second, and the third. Thus, while the first counts 5, Queen, Ace once, the latter counts it 6 times, once for each permutation of those values.